# Building Oracle DB; Good Directory Layout

Tags: oracle, database-schema

I'm looking for advice on how to best organize a new Oracle schema and dependent files in my project directory - with the sequences, triggers, DDL, etc. I've been using one monolothic file called schema.sql for some time, but I'm wondering if there's a best practice? Something like...

```
database/
   tables/
      person.sql
      group.sql
   sequences/
      person.sequence
      group.sequence
   triggers/
      new_person.trigger
```

Penny for your thoughts or a URL that I may have missed!

Thank you!

Comment: You could have a look at the approach taken by liquibase http://www.liquibase.org/tutorial-using-oracle

Answer (score 3):

Storing DDL by object type is a reasonable approach-- anything is likely to be easier to navigate than a monolithic SQL script.  Personally, though, I'd much rather have DDL organized by function.  If you're building an accounting system, for example, you probably have a series of objects to manage accounts payable and a separate set of objects to manage accounts receivable along with some core objects for managing the general ledger accounts.  That would lead to something along the lines of

```
database/
  general_ledger/
    tables/
    packages/
    sequences/
  accounts_receivable/
    tables/
    packages/
    sequences/
  accounts_payable/
    tables/
    packages/
    sequences
```

As the system gets more complex, that hierarchy would naturally get deeper over time.  This sort of approach would more naturally mirror the way non-database code is stored in source control.  You wouldn't have a single directory of Java classes in a directory structure like

```
middle_tier/
  java/
    Foo.java
    Bar.java
```

You would organize the classes that implement the same sorts of business logic together and separate from the classes that implement different bits of business logic.

Answer (score 2):

One item to consider is those SQLs which can act as 'latest only' scripts. These include CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE/FUNCTION/TRIGGER etc. You run the latest version and you are not worried about what may have previously existed in the database.

On the other hand you have tables where you may start off with a CREATE TABLE followed by several ALTER TABLEs as changes to the schema evolve. And if you are doing an upgrade you may want to apply several of the ALTER TABLE scripts (preferably in order).

I'd argue against a 'functional grouping' unless it is really obvious where the lines are drawn. You probably don't want to be in a position where you have a USERS table in one group and a USER_AUTHORITIES in another and an AUTHORITY group in a third.

If you do have decent separation, then they are probably in separate schemas and you do want to keep schemas distinct (since you can have the same object names in different schemas).

Answer (score 0):

The division-by-object-type arrangement, with the addition of a "schema" directory below the database directory works well for me.

I've worked with source control systems that have the additional division-by-function layer - if there are many objects it adds additional searching if you're trying to cross-reference the source control file with the object that you see in a database GUI navigator that generally groups objects by type.  It's also not always clear how an object should be classified this way.

Consider adding a "grants" directory for the grants made by that schema to other schemas or roles, with one file per grantee.  If you have "rule-based" grants such as "the APPLICATION_USER role always gets SELECT on all of schema X's tables", then write a PL/SQL anonymous block to perform this action.  (You might be tempted to reverse-engineer the grants after they get put in place by some ad-hoc method, but it's easy to miss something when new tables or views are added to the application).

Standardize on a delimiter for all scripts and you'll make your life easier if you start deploying through a build utility such as Ant.  Using "/" (vs. ";") works for both SQL statements as well as PL/SQL anonymous blocks.

Answer (score 0):

In our projects we use somewhat combined approach: we have a core of our program as a root and other functionalities in subfolders:

```
root/
  plugins/
    auth/
    mail/
    report/
```

etc.

In all these folders we have both DDL and DML scripts almost all of them can be run more that once, e.g. all packages are defined as `create or replace...`, all data insertion scripts check whether data already exists and so on. This gives us the opportunity to rus almost all scripts without thinking that we can crash something.

Obviously this scenario can't be applied for `create table` and similar statements. For these scripts we have manually written small bash script that extracts specified files and runs them not failing on particular ORA errors, like: `ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object`.

Also all files are mixed in the directories but differ with extensions: `.seq` goes for sequence, `.tbl` goes for table, `.pkg` goes for package interface, `.bdy` goes for package body, `.trg` goes for trigger an so on...

Also we have a naming convention denoting prefixes for all of our files: we can have `cl_oper.tbl` table with `cl_oper.seq` and `cl_oper.trg` sequence and triggers and `cl_oper_processing.pkg` together with `cl_oper_processing.bdy` with logic for mentioned objects. With this naming convention in file managers it's very easy to see all the files connected with some unit of logic for our project (whilst the grouping in directories by object types does not provide this).

Hope this information helps you somehow. Please leave comments if you have any questions.